# DOM table getting the rel attribute

Tags: jquery, dom

Im trying to get the rel attribute on the sibling of the checked radiobutton within the table:

```
<table id="table-handing-subjects-content" class="table-content-all">
  <tbody>
    <tr for="handling-subject0">
      <td style="width:10%;">
        <input id="handling-subject[0]" type="radio" value="2" name="handling_subject">
      </td>
      <td style="width:25%;">
        <label for="handling-subject[0]"> economics</label>
      </td>
      <td style="width:15%;">
           <label for="handling-subject[0]"> firstyear</label>
      </td>
      <td style="width:20%;">
           <label id="ref-sec-id[0]" for="handling-subject[0]" rel="36"> black</label>
      </td>
      <td style="width:30%;">
         <label for="handling-subject[0]"> asdf,asdf asdf</label>
      </td>
 </tr>
 <tr for="handling-subject1">
   <td style="width:10%;">
      <input id="handling-subject[1]" type="radio" value="3" name="handling_subject">
   </td>
   <td style="width:25%;">
      <label for="handling-subject[1]"> math</label>
   </td>
   <td style="width:15%;">
      <label for="handling-subject[1]"> firstyear</label>
   </td>
   <td style="width:20%;">
      <label id="ref-sec-id[1]" for="handling-subject[1]" rel="36"> black</label>
   </td>
   <td style="width:30%;">
       <label for="handling-subject[1]"> asdf,asdf asdf</label>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr for="handling-subject2">
   <td style="width:10%;">
        <input id="handling-subject[2]" type="radio" value="3" name="handling_subject">
   </td>
   <td style="width:25%;">
        <label for="handling-subject[2]"> math</label>
   </td>
   <td style="width:15%;">
        <label for="handling-subject[2]"> firstyear</label>
   </td>
   <td style="width:20%;">
        <label id="ref-sec-id[2]" for="handling-subject[2]" rel="32"> level-up</label>
   </td>
   <td style="width:30%;">
         <label for="handling-subject[2]"> asdf,asdf asdf</label>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

Im trying to get the label with id="ref-sec-id" of the checked radiobutton with this

```
   $('input[name=handling_subject]:checked').parent().parent().parent().children().find("td:eq(3)").children().attr("rel");
```

But i guess Im only getting the first row with unchecked radiobutton. plss help.. and thanks in advance

Comment: i edited it. Plss reload

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[name=handling_subject]:checked").closest('tr').find('[rel]').attr('rel')
```

Your HTML causes the inputs to have an inconsistent number of parents relative to the table.

You should also make all of the `id` attributes on the labels unique, but that shouldn't have any effect on your ability to use the above selector.

Comment: tnx. now i get it. thats why.